# Swig generted class in swig interface file

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm using SWIG to generated Java classes and I have 3 different classes that one dependant on the others.
SWIG makes pointers to this classes because it didn't know about it, I need that SWIG uses the Java classes that created and not the pointers that SWIG creates.

How can I do this?

I have c++ function like this:

```
bool foo(class1& parm);
```

Now I use SWIG to create `class1` in Java and I want to make SWIG to wrap `foo` in Java with the parameter `class1` that it created and not `SWIG_P_class1`. I don't have any way to do this.

Comment: Have you made any efforts of your own?

Answer (score 0):

Swig hides away details like the actual classes or objects used.  If you want to access the real Java objects and class I suggest you use JNI (which gives you access to everything and is likely to be faster)

Answer (score 0):

For types that SWIG knows nothing about (i.e. hasn't seen anything more than a forward declaration) the best wrapper it can generate roughly mirrors what you can do with a forward declared class in C++ - it gets wrapped as something that behaves like an opaque pointer. This is the `SWIG_P_class1` you're seeing. You can do sensible things with this, e.g. if you have a method that returns references or pointers to instances you could call that to get an object to pass to `foo`.

However you probably don't want to use that much in real interfaces, so given a header file we want to wrap that looks like:

```
class class1;

bool foo(class1& parm);
```

You can wrap it sensibly by giving SWIG a partial (or complete if you prefer) definition of the `class1`, e.g.:

```
%module test

class class1 {
};

%include "test.hh"
```

will cause a sensible `class1` and `foo` to be exposed on the Java side, so you could use them in Java as in:

```
test.foo(new class1());
```

exactly as you'd hope.

You will of course need to provide the generated C++ sufficient knowledge of the `class1` class, exactly as you would with any other C++ code. The easiest way to do that is to make your SWIG interface look something like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "class1_defined_here.hh"
%}

class class1 {
};

%include "test.hh"
```